# Index rebuild freezes database even with online=on

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL database that is hosted on Azure and its size is 712 Gb.

Whenever I try to rebuild the indexes with `(online=on)` the website works fine for a few minutes then freezes, DTU goes to 100% and I have to stop the query execution. This happens even with a single index rebuild.

We have very high fragmentation and we need to rebuild the index regularly.

We have users accessing the website from all around the world so it's really difficult to find a non-peak time and rebuild it.

Can someone please propose a solution?

Comment: Consider `REORGANIZE` instead of `REBUILD`.

Comment: "We have very high fragmentation and we need to rebuild the index regularly." Not necessarily.  In addition to REORGANIZE, consider updating statistics instead.

Answer (score 2):

I read in the [Guidelines for Online Index Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/guidelines-for-online-index-operations) that setting `MAXDOP` might be needed to preserve some processors for other activities.

> On multiprocessor computers that are running SQL Server 2016, index statements may use more processors to perform the scan and sort operations associated with the index statement just like other queries do. **You can use the MAXDOP index option to control the number of processors dedicated to the online index operation**. In this way, you can balance the resources that are used by index operation with those of the concurrent users.

So say you have eight processors, you could force the rebuild action to only use four processors:

```
... REBUILD WITH (ONLINE=ON,MAXDOP=4);
```

Comment: amazing, I currently have maxdop=0 (max) any suggestion? do you know how I can find the number of processors in Azure? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Techy I do not, but if I had to guess, I would take DTU to be a processor. In any case, it's worth to try out with e.g. MAXDOP to 1 and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, to me it makes sense but unfortunately regardless if I set it to 1 or 2 the database freezes even faster than running the query without maxdop

Comment: @Techy I'm sorry to hear that. Maybe something else in the article I linked jumps out? Maybe try a DOP equal to half the DTU's?

Comment: I tried my best to know how many processors do we have but couldn't find it. I tried setting it to 1 or 2 which I feel is the minimum. I'm trying another way now (experimenting on different indexes) Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Another weird thing, I found this as a particular problem to some primary key clustered indexes while other indexes work just fine.

Comment: @Techy I'm also reading in the document I linked to, that an index rebuild can cause a deadlock: `the online index operation can cause a deadlock when it interacts with database updates because of user or application activities`. Not sure if that is the case.

Comment: It might be, but it's really weird that it's specific to non-PK indexes... the problem is that the database it growing in size, one of the PK indexes is above 200GB!

Comment: @Techy That is unwieldly big. I can't say I have experience in these sort of cases. If an index reorganize isn't sufficient, you really need to rebuild, maybe doing it offline is an option? It will probably take a long time stil. Maybe dba.stackexchange has better experts in this matter, you might ask there if you're not getting proper responses here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use sharding to distribute data of your database geographically. You then will be able to identify different maintenance windows for each geographic location, and the time to make maintenance will be shorter. This will also improve performance. You can learn more on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-scale-introduction) article.

With big databases and users connected 24 x 7, you need to use index reorganize and update only statistics that need to be updated (sp_updatestats) to minimize the time needed for maintenance and the impact to users.